# Custom Grid System

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I've created this grid that you see below:
[image: Example:]

without using bootstrap or other grid system.
Now I want to use bootstrap but I don't know if it's possible to create something like that, because it's not saving the equal spaces between the boxes,

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/xe6h7grs/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="box">A</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="box">B</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="box">
                C
                <ul>
                    <li>example</li>
                    <li>example</li>
                    <li>example</li>
                    <li>example</li>
                    <li>example</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="box">HEY</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="box">HEY</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="box">HEY</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap columns have left/right padding which may cause you unwanted spacing.  You can override this padding as you need to.

```
.col-xs-4 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xe6h7grs/1/

Or you can set the box class margin to a negative value to override the padding.

```
.box {
    margin: 1px -15px;
}
```

Also note for responsiveness, default column width is 100% and the specified sizes scale up.  This means that if you only declare md, xs and sm will be 100%.

Comment: and what if I want to remove the white space between the two rows? is there a way that I can make it more flexible?

Comment: There are many, and I mean many way, users attempt to match column heights (flexbox, padding/margins, JavaScript, table grids).  Pick your poison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height.  None are perfect so you need to choose the one that fits your responsiveness and compatibility needs.

Answer (score 0):

1) Generally speaking, you should not arbitrarily alter the Grid itself. Instead you can use a custom class:

```
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

This will allow you to adjust the column padding (and whatever other rules concerning columns) to whatever you need.

2) Or if you use SASS you can use the below [Variable](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) to adjust the padding.

//** Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.

```
 $grid-gutter-width:         30px !default;
```

3) And you can use a custom build as well if it makes sense. See [Customize Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system).

**See examples in Snippet.**

```css
body,
html {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.lightblue {
  background: lightblue;
}
.red {
  background: #f00;
}
.box {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}
.box2 {
  background: #f00;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 1px;
}
.box3 {
  background: #444;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Original Grid</h3>

  <div class="row lightblue">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">C
        <ul>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row lightblue">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">HEY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">HEY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">HEY</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Your example Grid</h3>

  <div class="row lightblue">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box2">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box2">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box2">C
        <ul>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row lightblue">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box2">HEY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box2">HEY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box2">HEY</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Columns with Zero Padding | Outcome</h3>

  <div class="row no-gutter red">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box3">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box3">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box3">C
        <ul>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
          <li>example</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row no-gutter red">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box3">HEY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box3">HEY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box3">HEY</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```